# Adhoc on Archlinux with Network-manager

Tags: arch-linux, connection-sharing, repeater, ad-hoc-network

I'm trying to make dnsmasq work to use it with NetworkManager to create an adhoc connection on Archlinux and there may be other stuff left to do after to make it work ...

There is how : ( https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dnsmasq and https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=6431)

```
pacman -S dnsmasq
mkdir /etc/dnsmasq
mv /etc/resolv.conf /etc/dnsmasq
cd /etc
echo nameserver 127.0.0.1 > resolv.conf
mv rc.conf rc.conf.save 
sed  '/DAEMON/s/network/network dnsmasq.local/g' rc.conf.save>rc.conf
cd rc.d
sed  '/-z/s/dnsmasq/dnsmasq -r /etc/dnsmasq/resolv.conf /g' dnsmasq>dnsmasq.local
/etc/rc.d/dnsmasq.local start
/etc/rc.d/network restart
```

I got a problem with :

```
sed  '/-z/s/dnsmasq/dnsmasq -r /etc/dnsmasq/resolv.conf /g' dnsmasq>dnsmasq.local
```

In resume it say that's the .../s/... is not a known option ...

Comment: I don't know how that guy in the forums supposes that sed command to work. You have to escape the slashes like this: `sed  '/-z/s/dnsmasq/dnsmasq -r \/etc\/dnsmasq\/resolv.conf /g' dnsmasq>dnsmasq.local` or choose another delimiter in sed like this `sed  '/-z/s!dnsmasq!dnsmasq -r /etc/dnsmasq/resolv.conf !g'`

Comment: It make dnsmasq work but it's not the stuff I need to do, should be something else ...

Wiki pages most peoples tell me to try :

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Ad-hoc_networking

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Sharing_ppp_connection_with_wlan_interface

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Software_Access_Point

The problem is they uses specific options for hardware mostly ...